# AttributeError 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, csv, replace, attributes, data-analysis

I am getting the Attribute error:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

In my program i am reading 3 different files. When i run the code it works perfectly, but only for one of the files. I have no clue why the other 2 files give me this error. I was excpecting to get the amount of days in a given month from a .csv file. i am writing the code in python. If you need any aditional information please ask :)

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
def getAMSdata(fileName):


startTid = [] 
sluttTid = []
forbruk = []

dataframe= pd.read_csv(fileName, sep=";") 
startTid = dataframe["Fra"].tolist()
sluttTid = dataframe["Til"].tolist()
forbruk = dataframe["KWH 60 Forbruk"].tolist()

return startTid,sluttTid,forbruk #returnerer lister

dataLists = getAMSdata("data/meteringvalues-mp-xxxxx-consumption-202101.csv") 

for i in range(len(dataLists[2])):
dataLists[2][i] = float(dataLists[2][i].replace(',','.'))

def getDayCount(timeStampList):
    dayCount= len(timeStampList) // 24
    return dayCount

def getMonth(dateAndTimeStr):

months = ["Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"]
monthStr = int(dateAndTimeStr[3:5])
month = months[monthStr - 1]

return month

def getDays(timeStampList):
#-------------------------------------
    dayList = []

    for i in range(0, len(timeStampList)):
    
         dayList.append(int(timeStampList[i][0:2]))
#-------------------------------------
         return dayList

 def getHours(timeStampList):
#-------------------------------------
     hourList = []
     for i in range(len(timeStampList)):
    
         hourList.append(int(timeStampList[i][11:13]))
#-------------------------------------
     return hourList

 import os

 files = os.listdir('data')

 def selectDataFile(fileIndex):

      return files[fileIndex]

 selectDataFile(0)
 def printMainMenu():
print('\n')
print('------ MAIN MENU ------')
print('\n')
print('1) Show all the data files available.')
print('2) Select the year and month to study.')
print('3) Go to graph and statistics menu.')
print('4) Quit.')
return

def printMonth():
print('1 : January')
print('2 : February')
print('3 : March')
print('4 : April') 
print('5 : May')
print('6 : June')
print('7 : July')
print('8 : August')
print('9 : September')
print('10 : October')
print('11 : November')
print('12 : December')

def processMainMenu(x, currentfile):
print('\n')

if x=='1' :
    print("Files availables : ")
    for i in range(len(files)):
        print(files[i])
    return True, currentfile

elif x=='2':
    
    year = input('\nSelect the year : ')
    
    if year != '2020' and year != '2021':
        print('There is no data for ', year)
        return True, currentfile
    
    printMonth()
    month = input('\nSelect the month : ')
    
    if year == '2021' and month == '1':
        currentfile = selectDataFile(1)
        return True, currentfile
    
    elif year =='2020' and month == '11':
        currentfile= selectDataFile(0)
        return True, currentfile
    
    elif year =='2020' and month == '12':
        currentfile = selectDataFile(2)
        return True, currentfile

    else :
        print('There is no data for the selected year and month.')
        return True, currentfile
    
elif x=='3':
    if currentfile == '':
        print('Select a file before going to the graph and stats menu.')
        return True, currentfile
    printGraphStatMenu()
    y = input('Chose an option by entering its index number : ')
    keepGoing = processGraphStatMenu(y, currentfile)
    return keepGoing, currentfile

elif x=='4': 
    return False, currentfile

else:
    print('Please enter a proper index number.')
    
return True,currentfile

def printGraphStatMenu():
print('\n')
print('   ------ GRAPH AND STATISTICS MENU ------')
print('\n')
print('   STATISTICS :  ')
print('     1) Show the number of days in the month.')
print('     2) Show the average consumption in the month.')
print('     3) Show the average hourly consumption per day.')
print('     4) Chose an hour of the day and show its consumption.')
print('     5) Show highest consumption and the hour it is reached.')
print('     6) Show the average power peak in the month.')
print('     7) Show standard deviation for the hourly consumption.')
print('   GRAPHS :  ')
print('     8) Graph the daily consumption.')
print('     9) Graph an average day.')
print('     10) Quit.')

def processGraphStatMenu(y, currentfile):

data = getAMSdata(str('data/' + currentfile))


for i in range(len(data[2])):
    data[2][i] = float(data[2][i].replace(',','.'))

if y == '1':
    print('\n     THERE ARE ', getDayCount(data[0]),' DAYS IN THE MONTH.')
    return True
    
elif y== '2':
    print('\n     THE AVERAGE CONSUMPTION IN THE MONTH IS :', getAverage(data[2]), 'KWH.')
    return True

elif y=='3':
    avgDay = pd.DataFrame(getAvgDay(data[2], getHours(data[0])))
    print('\n     THE AVERAGE HOURLY CONSUMPTION PER DAY IS :', avgDay , 'KWH.')
    return True

elif y=='4':
    hour = int(input('     Select an hour by entering an integer between 0 and 23 :'))
    if hour < 0 or hour > 23 :
        print('\n     Please enter an hour between 0 and 23.')
        return True
    
    hours = getHours(data[0])
    sameHourCons = []
    for i in range(len(hours)):
        if hours[i] == hour :
            sameHourCons.append(data[2][i])
    index = range(1, len(sameHourCons) + 1)
    sameHourConsDF = pd.DataFrame(sameHourCons, index = index)
    print('\n     HERE IS THE CONSUMPTION AT HOUR ', hour, ' FOR EACH DAY OF THE MONTH : \n', sameHourConsDF)
    return True

elif y == '5':
    peakCons, peakDate, peakHour = findPeakInterval(data[2], getDays(data[0]), getHours(data[0]))
    print('\n     THE HIGHEST CONSUMPTION IS : ', peakCons, ' KWH. IT IS REACHED ON DAY ', peakDate, ' AT HOUR ', peakHour,'.')
    return True

elif y == '6':
    print('\n     THE AVERAGE POWER PEAK IN THE MONTH IS : ', getEffectPeak(data[2]), 'KWH')
    return True

elif y == '7':
    hourlyCons = getDailyConsumption(data[2], getDays(data[0]))
    print('\n     THE STANDARD DEVIATION FOR THE HOURLY CONSUMPTION IS :', getStdDev(hourlyCons, getAverage(hourlyCons)), 'KWH.')
    return True

elif y == '8':
    plotDailyConsumption(getDailyConsumption(data[2], getDays(data[0])), getMonth(data[0][0]))
    return True

elif y == '9':
    plotAvgDay(getAvgDay(data[2], getHours(data[0])), getMonth(data[0][0]))
    return True
    
elif y == '10' :
    return False

else:
    print('\n     Please enter a proper index number.')

return

def main():

keepGoing = True
currentfile = ''
while(keepGoing):

    printMainMenu()
    x = input('Chose an option by entering its index number : ')
    keepGoing, currentfile = processMainMenu(x, currentfile)
    
print('Bye !')
return 

main()
```

I skipped some parts that I assumed were unimportant for my error
fyi this is my first major code and my first stack overflow question

Comment: Welcome! We do need more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: But conceptually you are trying to apply a string function to a float object. Not sure how you're reading the file, but you're either explicitly casting floats or using a module that does so

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way we can point out your mistake.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're coding in Python.

In Python, you cannot write `.replace('x', 'y')` for floats, but you can for strings. Different types have different properties.

A very basic way of replacing floats with another number is as follows:

```
a = 5.5
if a == 5.5:
    a = 9.3
```

There are many ways to change a float, but which one to use depends on your specific problem.